# Why does my hair(and plastic-y ribbons) do that?

Tags: friction

I’ve been doing this since I was a child, could never really understand why. So, if I take a single hair from my head and hold it firmly between the nails of my finger and thumb, and then while keeping the firm hold, drag through the entire length of the hair strand, it becomes so very curly.

Only the part of the hair strand subjected to this goes curly, not the rest (as you will find in the ‘hair after’ picture.) I researched online and learned that curly hair has more disulphide bonds in a strand than straight hair as well as follicular asymmetry. What did my dragging do to the hair to cause an effect similar to these natural reasons(disulphide bonds and follicular asymmetry) on the strand. Very curious.
Can someone explain why this happens?
The same thing happens with a ribbon(plastic not cloth) and scissors, but it’s a non biological polymer in case of the ribbon. Why does it happen to a ribbon?

Also, I advise you to try it, you might find it mildly amusing.

Note: originally asked this question on biology stackexchange but commenters asked me to post this to physics since this phenomenon is part of a more general phenomenon(like the one you can do with a plastic-y ribbon and scissors). So I posted this here.

Images are in the sequence of: 1.hair before 2.hold like so and 3.hair after[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

When you drag along the strand or ribbon, you break fibres along one side. This means that the two sides have different lengths (one has continuous fibres and the other fibre segments plus breaks). This will make the strand or ribbon curl towards the unbroken side.

Comment: you might notice that I am holding the strand from two (approximately) diametrically opposite ends, so if I am breaking fibres as you say, I must be breaking them at diametrically opposite ends, which would nullify the effect. In the ribbon’s case, yes I think you are right, because the scissor surface is dragged along one side. I must confess I’m not entirely convinced on the hair strand’s case. But since no other explanation seems evident, I rest my case for now.